# How to get facebook login status through $cordovaOauth.facebook

Tags: angularjs, facebook, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I am using [nraboy's facebook login plugin](https://github.com/nraboy/ng-cordova-facebook-example) to do a facebook login system for my Ionic Framework Application. After testing that plugin, everything works well such as getting user's information(profile image/name/email).

The plugin will retrieve the access token from Facebook and allows me to save in my local database of the application which will allows me to check if the token is still valid whenever the user will open the application.

I am now trying to bypass the login page without entering the user's username and password. I have did some research, using a function getloginstatus() from facebook will check if the user is already connected to facebook but this function doesn't seems to be available in this plugin.

getloginstatus code from Facebook

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
        var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
        // but has not authenticated your app
    } else {
        // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
    }
 });
```

Is there a way to check the login status by using this plugin?

Comment: How are you creating this FB object?  Are you passing in the access token obtained fro $cordovaOauth?

Comment: @NicRaboy Hi, I am actually trying to bypass the login authentication by checking if the user is already connected and authorized to their facebook. Which means, if the user is logged in from the official facebook application in the phone, the user doesn't have to enter their username/password. It should automatically authenticate without the access token.

Comment: This FB object is a code i got from Facebook. It will not work with cordovaOauth. Was hoping if cordovaOauth has this function. Something from this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus

Comment: cordovaOauth only serves one purpose, to get access tokens.  It offers no other functionality.  What you do with the access token is up to you, whether it be to pass into the Facebook JS SDK or to use the RESTful APIs.

Comment: So to get the access token, the user will still have to login. I understand. Thanks @NicRaboy. Please do create an answer so I could Accept it too.

Comment: Access tokens are valid for one hour.  You can store the token along with the expiration time.  If the token is still valid, do not start the oauth flow for the user to sign in.